# What datatype does this variable hold?

Tags: python

```
variable = ['yes', 'no']
```

Just wondering what data type the variable above is and the definition of that data type.

Comment: it's a list of string...you can find lot of good online documentation about python

Comment: tip: when curious of a datatype, call `type()` on the variable: `type(variable)
<type 'list'>`

Comment: You can always the the type with `type(variable)`

Comment: thanks... sorry if the question was a bit dumb. i'm completely new to this.

Comment: No worries, just remember to search the site first. Using Google is a good alternative, it will almost always return a reasonable question here, if it has already been made.